# How can I install swype on HTC Wildfire S?

Tags: swype, htc-wildfire-s

I have an HTC Wildfire S and want to install Swype.

I understand from a bit of searching that I need to download it.

When I search for "swype" in the marketplace there are dozens of results which all don't seem to install the Swype functionality.

Some forums even mention that this is [not possible](http://forum.swype.com/archive/index.php/t-2711.html?s=37cf53eab7ed664330f4f8cec2312935).

**How do I install Swype functionality on my HTC Wildfire S?**

Comment: Use Go Keyboard or SwiftKey X, dude..

Answer (score 4):

Swype uses a "closed" beta system to distribute its app rather than using the Market. You can register for the beta and get a download link for their installer by simply visiting the [Swype website](http://beta.swype.com).

Disclaimer: I have no idea if the Wildfire is "officially" supported, but QVGA screen support is noted for v3.0. The forum thread you linked to in your question is about 5 months old, and QVGA was not supported at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://beta.swype.com/ ?
You need to register with an email address to get a link to download the Swype installer.

Answer (score 1):

Swype developers pulled the app from the market in favour of deals with manufacturers and networks to have the app pre-installed on phones. So the only way to obtain it is to find a copy of the app apk file and manually install it. Note that there are different versions of the apk depending on the screen resolution (and possibly other factors) of the phone.

Answer (score -2):

go to new message, put your finger on text input box and hold, it'll bring up 'edit text', choose 'input method' then 'swype'.

Comment: What if Swype isn't installed?